# Using SQL Server function without creating it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

Is it possible to use a function in a SQL-query without creating it on the database? I'm trying to use a function to select the right data but I'm not allowed to change the database.

For example the following example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getSomeValue(@Id INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) AS
BEGIN
   ...
END

SELECT Customer.Id, dbo.getSomeValue(Customer.Id) AS Value FROM Customer
```

In this case I'd like to use the given function without creating it, is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: @Downvoter: Please ellaborate...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How is it possible to call a function which is not defined? **It's impossible.**

If the function doesn't contain complex procedural codes and can be written in a single expression, you can use the expression directly in the SQL select list like this:

```
SELECT Customer.Id, (your expression) AS Value FROM Customer
```

In `(your expression)` you can insert the simple calculation or predefined function.

Or you can use scala subquery:

```
SELECT Customer.Id, (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...) AS Value FROM Customer
```

The scala subquery should return only one row.

Comment: I'm using a function since I need recursive logic.

Comment: If you need recursive logic you can use CTE's

Comment: @Aquillo Yes, in many case you can use CTE or `connect by` (in Oracle) instead of recursive function. If the logic is too complex to make it as a query, you should define function.